Niche Female Regression or Isekaied Manhwa
The story is similar to many female-led isekai or regression manhwa, but with a unique twist. The heroine—who either gets isekaied into a book or regresses, I can't quite recall—finds herself battling against her main antagonist, the villainess. As the story unfolds, it turns out that the villainess is also either isekaied or a regressor.
The big reveal is that the villainess was originally the male lead’s first love. In the past, the two of them got married, and the villainess became pregnant. Unfortunately, after childbirth, she suffered from postpartum illness, which led to the deterioration of their marriage. In an attempt to fix her mistakes, the villainess tried to regress, believing that she and the male lead were "meant to be together" and that, if she could just correct things this time, they would be happy. However, when she regresses the new Heroine takes her place.
The villainess ends up doing many bad things, but her motivations stem from her belief that the male lead was supposed to be with her. Despite her efforts, the male lead finds happiness with the new heroine instead.
